Is my interpretation and proof of this equation correct: $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$?
Show that the following formula is true for all integers $n,k$ with $0\le{k}\le{n}$:
$$k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
I think the key lies in interpreting the problem as the number of ways to choose $1$ leader and $k-1$ followers from a group of $n$ people. Here’s how I see the two sides of the equation:

$k\binom{n}{k}$ first chooses $k$ members from $n$ eligible candidates — $\binom{n}{k}$. It then chooses $1$ leader from the $k$ members.
$n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ first chooses a leader from $n$ eligible candidates. It then chooses $k-1$ followers from the remaining $n-1$ candidates.

Is my reasoning correct?

Looks good.   Worth noting, perhaps, that it is easy to show it algebraically (I understand that the intent of the problem was to provide a combinatorial proof, but still).

@lulu: The algebraic proof is so simple that I don't see the point of proving it combinatorially.

@TonyK  Oh, I don't know.  Combinatorial proofs are always more enlightening.  Though I do see your point.
